# Unable to put two divs on same line using inline-block

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place two divs on same line.

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="first-box">   
    </div>
    <div id="second-box">
        this is second box
    </div>  
 </div>
```

css

```
div#page {
   background-color: slategrey;
   width: 960px;
   height:900px;
   margin: 20px;
   padding:20px;
   border:4px solid blue;
}
div#first-box{
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   display:inline-block;
   border:1px groove black;
}
div#second-box{
   display:inline-block;
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   padding:10px;
   border:1px solid green;
}
```

it place itself in same line when I use `vertical-align:top` in the second-box. But why it behave like that? Thanks
http://codepen.io/rajinirajadev/pen/xgBVab

Comment: Because by default.. inline elements are aligned to their baseline

Comment: add `float:left` to both the divs.

Comment: add `display: flex;` to `div#page`

Answer (score 3):

add this line in your second-box's css:

```
div#second-box{
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid green;
  vertical-align: top; // add this line
}
```

Comment: this is not the actual solution for the probem

Comment: This is the right solution. we can not use float (as suggested in most of the answers) cause that will effect other elements placed after this.

Comment: Yes we cannot use float, but we cannot use `vertical-align: top` either. What if there are many sibling elements in the same wrapper and above all, he don't need to do `vertical-align: top`. It is simple as to  
add `display: flex;` to div#page and it is done easily.

Answer (score 3):

**Short and Sweet**
My solution is very simple; I use less `CSS`, and the secret of aligning both `DIV` is to simply add `display: inline-flex;` to your `#page` DIV.
Below is the full code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="first-box">   
      This is the first box
    </div>
    <div id="second-box">
        this is second box
    </div>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  background:grey;
  color:white;
  
}
#page{
  padding:20px;
  display: inline-flex;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex; /* Safari */
}
#first-box, #second-box{
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding:10px
}
#second-box{
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Click [HERE](http://codepen.io/chrisN/pen/xgBOwO) for a working CODEPEN

**[UPDATE: 09/13/2020] IF YOU WANT TO USE CSS-GRID RATHER THAN INLINE-FLEX**

```css
#page2{
  padding:20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr) ) ;
}

#first-new-box, #second-new-box{
  height:150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding:10px
}
#second-new-box{
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="page2">
    <div id="first-new-box">   
      This is the first new box
    </div>
    <div id="second-new-box">
        this is the second new box
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
div#first-box{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px groove black;
  float: left;
}
```

live demo - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YNgqRN

Answer (score 2):

while adding contents to the first block also it works fine

```css
div#page {
background-color: slategrey;
width: 960px;
height:900px;
margin: 20px;
padding:20px;
border:4px solid blue;
}
div#first-box{
width:200px;
height:200px;
 display:inline-block;
border:1px groove black;
}
div#second-box{
display:inline-block;
width:200px;
height:200px;
padding:10px;
border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
    <div id="first-box">
      this is first box
    </div><div id="second-box">
        this is second box
    </div>  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ..

```css
div#page {
background-color: slategrey;
width: 960px;
height:900px;
margin: 20px;
padding:20px;
border:4px solid blue;
}
div#first-box{
width:200px;
height:200px;
display:inline-block;
border:1px groove black;
}
div#second-box{
display:inline-block;
width:200px;
height:200px;
border:1px solid green;
float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
    <div id="first-box">   
    </div>
    <div id="second-box">
        this is second box
    </div>  
 </div>
```

Comment: it is showing second box first which is not the requirement.

Comment: `float` is not an appropriate solution since it will mess the div positions

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="page">
<div id="first-box">   
<br clear="all">
</div>
<div id="second-box">
    this is second box
</div>
```

just  replace ur code with this one

Comment: what on earth is that BTW?

Comment: Whenever we calls a div inside a div ,complete row is occupied by the nested one . So to remove that we use clear all,right or left . And clear is used with break  so it is the simplest way to remove  extra space occupied by nested div .

Answer (score 1):

Change `display:table-cell` to each id & add `vertical-align:top` for text to display at top but it is not important for box alignment. And you are done. Remove any floats.

```css
div#page {
background-color: slategrey;
width: 960px;
height:900px;
margin: 20px;
padding:20px;
border:4px solid blue;
}
div#first-box{
width:200px;
height:200px;
display:table-cell;
border:1px groove black;
vertical-align:top;
}
div#second-box{
display:table-cell;
width:200px;
height:200px;
border:1px solid green;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
    <div id="first-box">   
    </div>
    <div id="second-box">
        this is second box
    </div>  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace Your css with below code:
Added Float:left, Position:relative, and Margin and it will not disturb you in further coding also.

```
div #page {
background-color: slategrey;
width: 960px;
height:900px;
margin: 20px;
padding:20px;
border:4px solid blue;
}

div #first-box{
width:200px;
height:200px;
display:inline-block;
border:1px groove black;
/* extra added 3 lines */
position: relative;
float:left;
margin:10px;
}


div #second-box{
display:inline-block;
width:200px;
height:200px;
padding:10px;
border:1px solid green;
/* extra added 3 lines */
position: relative;
float:left; 
margin:10px;
}
```